# What exactly is a ReceivePort / RawReceivePort? And how to find external method implementations in Dart?

Tags: dart, asynchronous, internals, dart-isolates

I'm currently experimenting with `Isolate`s in dart.

I'm trying to create a wrapper around an `Isolate` to make it more pleasant to use.

The desired interface is something along the lines:

```dart
abstract class BgIsolateInterface {
  Future<Response> send<Message, Response>(Message message);
}
```

I want to have a method that sends a message to the background interface and then return the response to the caller.

To achieve this I figured I have to create a new `RawReceivePort` or `ReceivePort` in the `send` function to reliably get the correct response.

But this would mean I'm essentially creating the port and discarding it. Going against the documentations which states

> Opens a **long-lived** port for receiving messages.

So my questions are:

1. what exactly are `ReceivePort`s and `RawReceivePort`s?
2. would my use case be valid i.e. have them be created only to read a single response?
3. should I look at another way of doing things?

Note: Please don't suggest the Flutter `compute` function as an alternative. I'm looking to do this in a long running isolate so I can share services / state between function calls. I'm just not showing this here to keep the question short.

Thank you very much!!!

Edit #1:
When providing the answer I realised there was also an underling question about how to read the Dart source, more specifically how to find `external` methods' implementations. That question was added to the title. The original question was just: `What exactly is a ReceivePort / RawReceivePort?`.

Answer (score 3):

Yesterday, I've searched across the source and I think, I now have the answers. If I'm wrong, anyone more involved with the engine please correct me. This is mostly my speculation.

TLDR:

1. `ReceivePort`/`RawReceivePort`s are essentially int ids with a registered message handler. The `SendPort` knows to which id i.e. `ReceivePort`/`RawReceivePort` it should send the data to.
2. Yes. But for another use case there is better way.
3. Change the interface, so we react to states / responses coming from the isolate i.e.

```dart
abstract class BgIsolateInterface<Message, Response> {
  void send(Message message);
  void listen(void Function(Response) onData);
}
```

---

**Long**

#1

I've looked at the implementation and I'm including my findings here also to put a note for my future self on how to actually do this if I ever need to.

First, if we look at the implementation of `ReceivePort` (comments removed):

```dart
abstract class ReceivePort implements Stream<dynamic> {
  external factory ReceivePort([String debugName = '']);

  external factory ReceivePort.fromRawReceivePort(RawReceivePort rawPort);

  StreamSubscription<dynamic> listen(void onData(var message)?,
      {Function? onError, void onDone()?, bool? cancelOnError});

  void close();
  SendPort get sendPort;
}
```

We can see the `external` keyword. Now, this means implementation is defined somewhere else. Great! Where?

Let's open the SDK source and look. We are looking for a class definition of the same name i.e. `ReceivePort` with a `@patch` annotation. Also it seems the Dart team follows the convention of naming the implementation files for these `external` methods with the suffix `_patch.dart`.

We then find the three of these patch files. Two for the `js` runtime, one for development and one for production, and one file for the `native`? runtime. Since, I'm not using Dart for the web, the latter is the one I'm interested in.

In the file: `sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/isolate_patch.dart` we see:

```dart
@patch
class ReceivePort {
  @patch
  factory ReceivePort([String debugName = '']) =>
      new _ReceivePortImpl(debugName);

  @patch
  factory ReceivePort.fromRawReceivePort(RawReceivePort rawPort) {
    return new _ReceivePortImpl.fromRawReceivePort(rawPort);
  }
}
```

Ok, so the implementation for `ReceivePort` is actually a library private `_ReceivePortImpl` class.

*Note: As you can see `factory` methods don't have to return the same class the method is defined in. You just have to return an object that `implements` or `extends` it. i.e., has the same contract.*

```dart
class _ReceivePortImpl extends Stream implements ReceivePort {
  _ReceivePortImpl([String debugName = ''])
      : this.fromRawReceivePort(new RawReceivePort(null, debugName));

  _ReceivePortImpl.fromRawReceivePort(this._rawPort)
      : _controller = new StreamController(sync: true) {
    _controller.onCancel = close;
    _rawPort.handler = _controller.add;
  }

  SendPort get sendPort {
    return _rawPort.sendPort;
  }

  StreamSubscription listen(void onData(var message)?,
      {Function? onError, void onDone()?, bool? cancelOnError}) {
    return _controller.stream.listen(onData,
        onError: onError, onDone: onDone, cancelOnError: cancelOnError);
  }

  close() {
    _rawPort.close();
    _controller.close();
  }

  final RawReceivePort _rawPort;
  final StreamController _controller;
}
```

Which as we can see is really just a wrapper around a `RawReceivePort` where the `handler` is a `StreamController.add` method. So, what about the `RawReceivePort`?

If we look at initial file where `ReceivePort` is defined we again see. It's just one `external` `factory` method and an interface for others.

```dart
abstract class RawReceivePort {
  external factory RawReceivePort([Function? handler, String debugName = '']);

  void set handler(Function? newHandler);

  SendPort get sendPort;
}
```

Luckily, its `@patch` version can also be found in the same place as the `ReceivePort`s.

```dart
@patch
class RawReceivePort {
  @patch
  factory RawReceivePort([Function? handler, String debugName = '']) {
    _RawReceivePortImpl result = new _RawReceivePortImpl(debugName);
    result.handler = handler;
    return result;
  }
}
```

Ok, again the actual implementation is `_RawReceivePortImpl` class.

```dart
@pragma("vm:entry-point")
class _RawReceivePortImpl implements RawReceivePort {
  factory _RawReceivePortImpl(String debugName) {
    final port = _RawReceivePortImpl._(debugName);
    _portMap[port._get_id()] = <String, dynamic>{
      'port': port,
    };
    return port;
  }

  @pragma("vm:external-name", "RawReceivePortImpl_factory")
  external factory _RawReceivePortImpl._(String debugName);

  close() {
    _portMap.remove(this._closeInternal());
  }

  SendPort get sendPort {
    return _get_sendport();
  }

  bool operator ==(var other) {
    return (other is _RawReceivePortImpl) &&
        (this._get_id() == other._get_id());
  }

  int get hashCode {
    return sendPort.hashCode;
  }

  @pragma("vm:external-name", "RawReceivePortImpl_get_id")
  external int _get_id();
  @pragma("vm:external-name", "RawReceivePortImpl_get_sendport")
  external SendPort _get_sendport();

  @pragma("vm:entry-point", "call")
  static _lookupHandler(int id) {
    var result = _portMap[id]?['handler'];
    return result;
  }

  @pragma("vm:entry-point", "call")
  static _lookupOpenPorts() {
    return _portMap.values.map((e) => e['port']).toList();
  }

  @pragma("vm:entry-point", "call")
  static _handleMessage(int id, var message) {
    final handler = _portMap[id]?['handler'];
    if (handler == null) {
      return null;
    }

    handler(message);
    _runPendingImmediateCallback();
    return handler;
  }

  @pragma("vm:external-name", "RawReceivePortImpl_closeInternal")
  external int _closeInternal();

  @pragma("vm:external-name", "RawReceivePortImpl_setActive")
  external _setActive(bool active);

  void set handler(Function? value) {
    final int id = this._get_id();
    if (!_portMap.containsKey(id)) {
      _portMap[id] = <String, dynamic>{
        'port': this,
      };
    }
    _portMap[id]!['handler'] = value;
  }

  static final _portMap = <int, Map<String, dynamic>>{};
}
```

OK, now we're getting somewhere. A lot is going on.

First thing to note are the: `@pragma("vm:entry-point")`, `@pragma("vm:entry-point", "call")` and `@pragma("vm:external-name", "...")` annotations. [Docs can be found here.](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/runtime/docs/pragmas.md)

Oversimplified:
[`vm:entry-point`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/runtime/docs/compiler/aot/entry_point_pragma.md) tells the compiler this class / method will be used from native code.
`vm:external-name` tells the compiler to invoke a native function which is registered to the name provided by the annotation.

For instance to know the implementation of:

```dart
@pragma("vm:external-name", "RawReceivePortImpl_factory")
  external factory _RawReceivePortImpl._(String debugName);
```

We have to look for `DEFINE_NATIVE_ENTRY(RawReceivePortImpl_factory`. And we find the entry in: `runtime/lib/isolate.cc`.

```cpp
DEFINE_NATIVE_ENTRY(RawReceivePortImpl_factory, 0, 2) {
  ASSERT(TypeArguments::CheckedHandle(zone, arguments->NativeArgAt(0)).IsNull());
  GET_NON_NULL_NATIVE_ARGUMENT(String, debug_name, arguments->NativeArgAt(1));
  Dart_Port port_id = PortMap::CreatePort(isolate->message_handler());
  return ReceivePort::New(port_id, debug_name, false /* not control port */);
}
```

We see the `port_id` is created by `PortMap::CreatePort` and is of type Dart_Port. Hmmm, and what is a the type definition for `Dart_Port`.

`runtime/include/dart_api.h`

```cpp
typedef int64_t Dart_Port;
```

OK so the actual internal representation of a `RawReceivePort` is a `signed int` stored in `64` bits, and some additional information like the type, state, debug names etc.

Most of the work is then being done in `PortMap::CreatePort` and other of its methods. I won't go in depth, because quite honestly I don't understand everything.

But from the looks of it the `PortMap` uses the `port_id` to point to some additional information + objects. It generates it randomly and makes sure the id is not taken. It also does a lot of different things but let's move on.

When sending a message through `SendPort.send`, the method essentially calls the registered entry `SendPortImpl_sendInternal_` which determines which port to send the information to.

*Note: `SendPort` essentially just points to its `ReceivePort` and also stores the id of the `Isolate` where it was created. When posting a message this id is used to determine what kind of objects can be sent through.*

The a message is created and passed to `PortMap::PostMessage` which in turn calls `MessageHandler::PostMessage`.

There the message is enqueued by a call to `MessageQueue::Enqueue`. Then a `MessageHandlerTask` is ran on the `ThreadPool`.

The `MessageHandlerTask` essentially just calls the `MessageHandler::TaskCallback` which eventually calls `MessageHandler::HandleMessages`.

There the `MessageHandler::HandleMessage` is called, but this function is implemented by a child class of `MessageHandler`.

Currently there are two:

- `IsolateMessageHandler` and
- `NativeMessageHandler`.

We are interested in the `IsolateMessageHandler`.

Looking there we see `IsolateMessageHandler::HandleMessage` eventually calls `DartLibraryCalls::HandleMessage` which calls `object_store->handle_message_function()`. *full chain: `Thread::Current()->isolate_group()->object_store()->handle_message_function()`*

The function `handle_message_function` is defined by the (dynamic?) macro `LAZY_ISOLATE(Function, handle_message_function)` in `runtime/vm/object_store.h`.

The property + stores created are used in: `runtime/vm/object_store.cc` by the: `ObjectStore::LazyInitIsolateMembers`.

`_RawReceivePortImpl` is registered to lazily load at the `isolate_lib.LookupClassAllowPrivate(Symbols::_RawReceivePortImpl())` call.

As well as, the methods marked with `@pragma("vm:entry-point", "call")`, including `static _handleMessage(int id, var message)`.

Which is the handler that `->handle_message_function()` returns.

Later the `DartLibraryCalls::HandleMessage` invokes it through `DartEntry::InvokeFunction` with the parameters `port_id` and the `message`.

This calls the `_handleMessage` function which calls the registered `_RawReceivePort.handler`.

---

#2

If we compare the Flutter's [`compute`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/d719463489218f9de5f7b8b2237cb256f7617e9f/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/_isolates_io.dart) method implementation. It spins up an `Isolate` and 3 `ReceivePort`s for every compute call. If I used `compute`, I would be spending more resources and loose context between multiple message calls I can have with a long-running `Isolate`. So for my use case I reason, creating a new `ReceivePort` everytime I pass a message shouldn't be a problem.

---

#3

I could use a different approache. But I still wish to have a long running `Isolate` so I have the flexibility to share context between different calls to the `Isolate`.

Alternative:
Would be following a `bloc` / `stream` style interface and have a method to assign a listener and a method to `send` or `add` a message event, and have the calling code listen to the responses received and act accordingly.

i.e. an interface like:

```dart
abstract class BgIsolateInterface<Message, Response> {
  void send(Message message);
  void addListener(void Function(Response) onData);
  void removeListener(void Function(Response) onData);
}
```

the down side is the `Message` and `Response` have to be determined when creating the class rather than simply when using the `send` method like the interface in my question. Also now some other part of the code base has to handle the `Response`. I prefer to handle everything at the `send` call site.

---

Note: [The source code of the `Dart` project](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk) is put here for presentation purposes. The live source may change with time. Its distribution and use are governed by their [LICENSE](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/bc0d63a93c68c5dc8e35c43b14d94b50b0b999d1/LICENSE).

Also: I'm not C/C++ developer so any interpretation of the C/C++ code may be wrong.

While this answer is long side-steps the questions a little bit, I find it useful to include the steps to search through the Dart source. Personally, I found it difficult initially to find where `external` functions are defined and what some of the annotation values mean. While these steps could be extracted into a separate question, I think it's useful to keep it here where there was a use case to actually dive deep.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: I'm not marking this as an accepted answer, because I'd rather get an answer from someone more knowledgable of the internals.